# Jmeter load test to multiple api controllers

Tags: c#, .net, api, jmeter, controller

is it possible to test multiple api controllers without specifying [controller] parameter

[image]

Like below, just writing down /api, testing both ValuesController and WeatherForecastController. Both of them are HttpGet and no need for any parameters.

[image]

Comment: It is a path on the server.  It is a shared folder on your machine.  So if you use a file explorer and in url type \\machine_name you see the shared folder(s).  You would need to put the executable in the root folder of the machine.

Comment: @jdweng can you share an example to be more specific?

Comment: Open a file explorer and look.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your screenshots are not very informative, my expectation is that you cannot have 2 controllers on a single API endpoint, they need to be different.

If you have something like this in your code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

then you should be able to access:

- ValuesController.cs as `/api/ValuesController`
- WeatherForecastController.cs as `/api/WeatherForecastController`

More information:

- [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)

Comment: in Jmeter you would do exactly the way you described. But imagine a scenario, there are 100 apis need to be tested. I do not want to write down everytime /api/... 
It is all about load test

Comment: If you have [Swagger documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - you should be able to use [swagger2yaml](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/) tool of [Taurus automation framework](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/). Alternatively you can print your Controllers names into a CSV file using [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and read it through  [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)